AWS RDS DB Connection not restarting
In reactive spring boot service, use case is like we are trying to receive message from SQS and process it but we are observing that the db connections are getting closed once queue is empty and application is idle for a while, once queue gets some message application receives it but rds connection does not get reinitiated.
Using below db related dependencies:

jasync-r2dbc-mysql:2.0.0
spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.3.0.M3
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.0.M3
name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.26'

DB Config

ConnectionPoolConfiguration configuration = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(connectionFactory)
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofHours(10)) // max idle time for a connection
                .maxSize(50)
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE))
                .metricsRecorder(new SimplePoolMetricsRecorder())
                .minIdle(5)
                .validationQuery(validationQuery)
                .initialSize(5)
                .build();

Logs:

once connection gets release, no log for obtaining connection

expecting when app receives messages post idle time, app obtains connection again.

I would strongly suggest to upgrade to a supported and final version of Spring Boot. You are on some old 2.3 version and a pre-release nonetheless as well. Move to something earlier and non pre-release.

cannot update to recent spring boot, is it required? is there any issue with the r2dbc lib

The r2dbc lib is old so if you try to use newer drivers it won't work, the version of Spring is a snapshot/pre-release version. I don't see why you cannot upgrade, just change the version and everything will be pulled in.
